# How to extract ID from the following JSON Object in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to extract all IDs from the below object using c#. 
in need of extracting a response value in  a  visual studio webtest.
The JSON is obtained using extract event.

```
 {
       "d": [
            {
              "__type": "QuestionZoneEditor.Entities.QuestionTag",
              "Id": 2080,
              "Name": "01",
              "Items": [
                "1a",
                "1b",
                "1c",
                "1d"
              ]
            },
            {
              "__type": "QuestionZoneEditor.Entities.QuestionTag",
              "Id": 2081,
              "Name": "02",
              "Items": [
                "2a(i)",
                "2a(ii)",
                "2b",
                "2c"
              ]
            },
            {
              "__type": "QuestionZoneEditor.Entities.QuestionTag",
              "Id": 2082,
              "Name": "03",
              "Items": [
                "3a",
                "3b",
                "3c"
              ]
            }
            }
          ]
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deserialize it to `JObject` after that take all `JObject` from the `JArray` and print the `Id`

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

foreach(JObject obj in result["d"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj["Id"]);
}
```

Full example: [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KOVokb)

Comment: add a reference of Json.NET: www.newtonsoft.com/